# Transaction with ReadCommited can block selects from other threads?

Tags: asp.net, oracle10g

I am trying to create unique policies with a ASP webservice and an Oracle 10.2g database.
I used to have a select query and an insert query to create policy numbers 
But yesterday the webservice was called from 2 different threads and in the same exactly time and two same policy numbers where created.
So i changed the code to use a transation.
If the webservice is called from two different threads in the same time how will the transaction work?
Will the readcommited block the second thread or i will face the same problem again?
The select query will work or will there be a problem?

```
Public Function ExecutePolicyNumberTransaction(ByVal conet_key As String) As String

    Dim policyno As String = ""
    Dim sqlstring As String = ""
    Dim conStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("con1").ConnectionString

    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(conStr)

        Dim transaction As OleDbTransaction

        Try
            connection.Open()
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)

            Dim insertcommand As New OleDbCommand()
            insertcommand.Connection = connection
            insertcommand.Transaction = transaction

            sqlstring = " INSERT into POLICYNUMBERS ( " & _
                " RECID, POLICYNO, REFERNCEKEY, ISUSED, ISUSEDDATE ) " & _
                " (SELECT NVL(MAX(RECID),0)+1, concat('P0130',concat(to_char(SUBSTR('000000', 0, 6-length(to_char(NVL(MAX(RECID),0)+1)))),to_char(NVL(MAX(RECID),0)+1))), '" & ref_key & "', 1, sysdate " & _
                " FROM POLICYNUMBERS )"

            insertcommand.CommandText = sqlstring
            insertcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            transaction.Commit()

            Dim selectcommand As New OleDbCommand()
            selectcommand.Connection = connection
            sqlstring = "SELECT POLICYNO FROM POLICYNUMBERS WHERE REFERNCEKEY = '" & ref_key & "'"                
            selectcommand.CommandText = sqlstring
            policyno = selectcommand.ExecuteScalar()


        Catch ex As Exception

            Try
                transaction.Rollback()

            Catch

            End Try

            policyno = ""

        End Try

    End Using

    Return policyno

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, readers don't block writers and writers don't block readers.  So neither session will block the other.

In a multi-user environment, however, you cannot generate primary keys using `MAX(key)+1` unless you specifically introduce some form of serialization.  Unless you want to build slow, unreliable systems, you don't want to introduce serialization.  Instead, you really, really, really want to be using a sequence to generate your keys.  Sequences are specifically designed to give primary keys to multiple concurrent sessions with a minimal overhead.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE policy_recid_seq
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 100; 

INSERT INTO policynumbers
  SELECT policy_recid_seq.nextval, ...
```

Comment: Thank you, i will go with this solution, trigger and sequence.